# How can I add element to an array calling a function with the onchange event?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, listbox, dom-events

I have a drop down list box and onchange I'm calling a function which should push this value to an array. The array keeps returning only one value.

Here is the js function:

```
function multSubType(sel){
    var objSel = document.getElementById('subType'+sel);
    var valSel = new Array();
    valSel.push(objSel.value);

}
```

Comment: could you  post your code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime the function executes, you're creating the array all over again.  Move the variable declaration and array assignment outside the scope of the function:

```
var valSel = new Array();

function multSubType(sel) {
    var objSel = document.getElementById('subType' + sel);
    valSel.push(objSel.value);
}
```